# Generate bulk integrated adresses

Tags: integrated-address

Is there a way in the GUI or CLI to generate a large amount of integrated addresses?

I'd like to have a bunch of addresses on hand so I don't have to open my wallet just to generate one.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be using subaddresses instead of integrated addresses. You can have a view only wallet so that if your server is compromised, your funds cannot be stolen.

If you really want to generate an integrated address without a wallet see here on how to do so: [Generate an integrated address using javascript in the browser?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/generate-an-integrated-address-using-javascript-in-the-browser)

Comment: Im fine using the wallets to create the integrated_addresses, I just would like to be able to make more than just 1 at a time.

Comment: The best way to create numerous addresses would be to write a python script using the monero-python package. Start the rpc: monero-wallet-rpc. Then run the script, that you have created.

Comment: A shell (e.g. bash) and the `monero-wallet-cli` is all that's needed. https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/12212/7493

Answer (score 2):

On *nix this is quite easy:

```
seq 5 | xargs -IN echo integrated_address N \
    | monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file MyWallet --password MyPass
```

Which would create 5 integrated addresses each with a payment ID (1 to 5).

No need for 3rd party libraries, javascript/python or browsers.